# aggregate order

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I am encountering some problems with my aggregate formula in mysql. I suspect that the error is because the computer is aggregating before sorting/ordering.
Could someone please suggest a better way to aggregate the count values, or help me with identifying the error in my code?
Here is the result table

```
date                hour         count     aggregate
August, 11 2012     20            1           170
August, 12 2012     19            1           58
August, 13 2012     14            1           44
August, 13 2012     15            1           75
August, 13 2012     21            1           72
August, 13 2012     23            1           80
```

The table is sorted by date first, and if two times are on the same day, then hour. Since the aggregate function is based on the count function, and the count column is just filled with 1s, the aggregate column **should** be showing 1, 2, 3, 4...etc 
Here is my query

```
SELECT   t1.original, t1.hour, t1.count,  SUM(t2.count) as aggregate 
FROM 
(SELECT  date(FROM_UNIXTIME( timecode)) as day,(hour(FROM_UNIXTIME( timecode)))  AS hour,(FROM_UNIXTIME( timecode)) AS original, COUNT(count)  as 'count'

 FROM sampleData
GROUP BY day, hour
order by original
) t1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT date(FROM_UNIXTIME( timecode)) as day, (hour(FROM_UNIXTIME( timecode) )) AS hour,(FROM_UNIXTIME( timecode)) AS original, COUNT(count)  as 'count'
FROM sampleData
GROUP BY day, hour
order by original
) t2 
on t1.hour >= t2.hour
GROUP BY t1.hour
ORDER BY t1.original
```

Comment: Why is t1.count in the second GROUP BY?

Comment: it was based off another code. in this case, it doesn't really affect the result. I'll remove it though.

Answer (score 0):

Two things stand out in your query.

First, the join doesn't make sense, because it is only on hour.

I would suggest replacing it with:

t1.day > t2.day or (t1.day = t2.day and t1.hour >= t2.hour)

Second, you have original and count in the outer SELECT, but they are not in the group by clause.  I think it is better practice to either have them in the group by clause or use an explicit aggregation function (MIN() or MAX(), in this case).  This can prevent errors.

Comment: I tried both suggestions. They both seem to help, however, the aggregate result is still inaccurate. It is 111234123412345... Could you elaborate more on the min() and max() aggregation function and how I could use them in my query?

Comment: the previous comment was using joining on  (t1.day = t2.day and t1.hour >= t2.hour). I tried using t1.day>=t2.day and the results were slightly better, 1,2,6,6,6,6,10,10,10,10,15,15,15,15,15. At least every 5 numbers or so the aggregate turns out to be right. (the last number of every set of repeated numbers is in the right position-1,2,6,10,15)

Comment: Try making your outer group by day, hour instead of just hour.

Comment: I tried that, the aggregate still remained as 1,2,6,6,6,6,10... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5aca9/82

Comment: If you are trying to count bins, then the outer query should be count(*), not count(count).  You are aggregating the number of rows at a lower level, instead of adding an increment to already summarized rows.

Comment: I was thinking of counting the amount of "counts" in each row. regardless, I incorporated your suggestions but the aggregate column remains the same.